# window scroll smooth in safari (looking for solution without using jQuery)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari

I saw a few posts about this issue and I understood that safari doesn't support it, now I saw only suggestions to do it with jQuery, here is not the case, I have 100% React based app and I don't want to use jQuery only for smooth scroll for safari, can anyone suggest any better / easier idea how to make it done ?

currently I'm using the smooth scrolling with window object,
I'll add that it works in perfectly fine in Chrome.

```
window.scroll({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth',
});
```

thank you!

Comment: Safari already support the behavior, did you try running app on different machines? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll#Browser_Compatibility

Comment: @DipenShah OP meant smooth scroll which is not supported by safari according to MDN document as of today

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - window.scroll({ behavior: 'smooth' }) not working in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229742/javascript-window-scroll-behavior-smooth-not-working-in-safari)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scroll), it has easing options.