# Is there a Safari equivalent for scroll-behavior: smooth;?

Tags: css, safari

I'm working on a single page portfolio which is navigated using a top-mounted navigation bar using href's. I use `scroll-behavior: smooth;` in my head's CSS and this makes the navigating smooth and pleasant to look at when looking at it in chrome. When loading the site using Safari this behavior is lost and the navigation is instant. Is there a Safari equivalent to this CSS functionality?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Safari 15.4 adds support for CSS `scroll-behavior` as detailed in the [15.4 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-15_4-release-notes#Web-API).

> Added support for the CSS scroll-behavior property and ScrollOptions, allowing smooth scrolling to anchors or via JavaScript.

Comment: I've tested and it works on 15.4 (Safari Technology Preview).

Comment: So it is... just found out myself. Finally... 

Comment: And it's broken: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=238497

Comment: Who thought this day would never come? I sure did. Now we can just use `html {scroll-behavior:smooth;}` instead of using custom polyfills. About time.

Answer (score 36):

Safari does not support `scroll-behavior: smooth`, you'll need some custom javascript to achieve the same effect. See this: [Javascript - window.scroll({ behavior: 'smooth' }) not working in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229742/javascript-window-scroll-behavior-smooth-not-working-in-safari)

Comment: Or just use the polyfill, as mentioned in the linked thread: https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll

Comment: I can confirm, the polyfill works great for me, as of today 4th june 2020, just load before your own stuff:
`<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/smoothscroll-polyfill@0.4.4/dist/smoothscroll.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @poulter7 works like a charm for me on all apple platforms.

Comment: @poulter7 ... see my production environment raesener.de if you like.

Comment: Safari 15.4 will include smooth scroll support: https://caniuse.com/css-scroll-behavior https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-15_4-release-notes#Web-API

Comment: Here is the answer that should be pinned: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71411937/2418066

Comment: @elmcrest then how to import it on js file?

Comment: @Ashik that depends on your setup and is related to general development with JS, so the topic is "js imports" I'd suggest. besides, just use the html tag.

Comment: I am using jquery, I don't want to use import export. for example in wow js I am using var wow = new Wow() in js file. Is there any way to do like that?

Answer (score 8):

## 2022 Update


**Safari support for smooth-scroll is still broken** and not customizable.

If you're looking for a simple way to enable it, you can take a look at the API I've been building for the past 4 years: https://github.com/CristianDavideConte/universalSmoothScroll.

It's **extremly fast**, easy to use and **it enables smooth-scroll on basically every browser** (IE is not supported) with high customization degree (easing, duration, interruptibility, etc...).

Below you'll find an example of how to use the API to quickly enable smooth-scroll on your website:

### Edit:

Since from [`UniversalSmoothScroll 6.0.0`](https://github.com/CristianDavideConte/universalSmoothScroll/releases/tag/6.0.0) the [`Ease-Functions`](https://github.com/CristianDavideConte/universalSmoothScroll/blob/master/docs/EaseFunctions.md) library has been converted to a `module`, this answer has been updated to make it work on stackoverflow. 
The problem is that stackoverflow [doesn't support modules in the javascript section of snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389108/support-javascript-es6-modules-in-code-snippets), so you'll find a workaround to make it work: you can ignore it since in a normal website you wouldn't use it.

```js
/*
 * In this example we will only customize the document's scrolling,
 * but the API fully support every custom scrollable container
 */
function init() {
  /* 
   * We tell the API which element is the one that scrolls the document
   * (useful whenever it's something like the body element, a custom container,
   * a framework specific container, etc...)
   */
  uss.setPageScroller(window); 

  /** 
   * This API function, enables the anchors' 
   * smooth-scrolling to the corresponding section
   */
  uss.hrefSetup();  
  
  /**
   * This API function, sets the easing of the pageScroller (that we set to window) to a
   * medium speed(the "QUART" part) ease-in-out function that last exactly 1 second.
   */
   uss.setStepLengthCalculator(EASE_IN_OUT_QUART(1000)); 
   
   /**
    * This API function allow us to stop the scrolling on a container.
    * In this case, we don't want any more scrolling 
    * if the user scrolls the document with the mousewheel.
    */
    window.addEventListener(
          "wheel", 
          () => uss.stopScrolling(window) 
    ); 
}



/*
 * YOU CAN IGNORE THIS PART.
 * This is just part of the workaround used on stackoverflow to make modules work. 
 * Basically it loads the init function whenever the document is fully loaded and the module is imported.
 * Check out this discussion for more informations: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389108/support-javascript-es6-modules-in-code-snippets
 */
document.addEventListener("readystatechange", () => document.readyState === "complete" && init());
```

```css
/* Just styling, none of this is necessary for the API */
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}

nav > a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 20vh;
  width: 15vw;
  background: rgba(20,20,20,0.5);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

nav > a:hover {
  background: rgba(20,20,20,0.6);
}

.horizontal-container {
  display:flex;
}

.page {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

#to1 {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 0%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
}


#to2 {
  background: linear-gradient(225deg, rgba(121,9,9,1) 0%, rgba(255,42,0,1) 100%);
}


#to3 {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(227,176,7,1) 0%, rgba(255,239,0,1) 100%);
}


#to4 {
  background: linear-gradient(315deg, rgba(7,101,6,1) 0%, rgba(0,255,98,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <!-- We include the API -->
    <script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/universalsmoothscroll@latest/universalsmoothscroll-min.js"></script>
    <!-- We include the API's easing library (this is optional) -->
    <script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/universalsmoothscroll@latest/universalsmoothscroll-ease-functions-min.js" type = "module"></script>
    
    <!-- 
      YOU CAN IGNORE THIS PART.
      This is just part of the workaround used on stackoverflow to make modules work.  
      It import the module and turns the import into a global variable.
      Check out this discussion for more informations: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389108/support-javascript-es6-modules-in-code-snippets
     -->
    <script type = "module">
      import {EASE_IN_OUT_QUART} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/universalsmoothscroll@latest/universalsmoothscroll-ease-functions-min.js";
      window.EASE_IN_OUT_QUART = EASE_IN_OUT_QUART;
    </script>
  </head>


  <body>
    <nav> <!-- header -->
      <a href="#to1"><p>Blue</p></a>
      <a href="#to2"><p>Red</p></a>
      <a href="#to3"><p>Yellow</p></a>
      <a href="#to4"><p>Green</p></a>
    </nav>
    <!-- Website pages -->
    <div class="horizontal-container">
      <div id="to1" class="page"></div>
      <div id="to2" class="page"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="horizontal-container">
      <div id="to3" class="page"></div>
      <div id="to4" class="page"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

More usage examples can be found at: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65269017/horizontal-smooth-momentum-scrolling/65288206#65288206) and [the official playground](https://cristiandavideconte.github.io/universalSmoothScroll/) or [my website](https://cristiandavideconte.github.io/myPersonalWebPage).

Comment: I suggest you run a performance test because demos are very laggy for me.

Comment: Version 6.0.0 of the API should have resolved all the performance issues with some functions being up to 69x faster than the v5.1.2 counterparts.

Comment: This won't work with scroll-snap-type, but native smooth scroll does

Comment: Correct, scroll-snap-type breaks (almost) all smooth scrolling libraries and it's specified in the FAQ section of the API: https://github.com/CristianDavideConte/universalSmoothScroll/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#q-can-i-use-the-api-scrolling-methods-on-containers-that-have-the-scroll-snap-type-css-property-. A snap-scrolling extension for the USS API is currently under developement

Answer (score 7):

According to the comment of [elmcrest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3975172/elmcrest), it works.

```
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/smoothscroll-polyfill@0.4.4/dist/smoothscroll.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I found that this does work pretty well, except it doesnt work for `element.scrollBy()`.

Answer (score 2):

you can solve the problem like that:

```
jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('html').offset().top
      }, 800)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery there is a equivalent for scroll-behavior: smooth.

Try this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
}, 1500);
```

Chanze zero to you desired postion.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('a[href*="#"]').not('[href="#"]').not('[href="#0"]').click(function (t) {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, "") == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, "") && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var e = $(this.hash);
        e = e.length ? e : $("[name=" + this.hash.slice(1) + "]"), e.length && (t.preventDefault(), $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: e.offset().top
        }, 600, function () {
            var t = $(e);
            if (t.focus(), t.is(":focus")) return !1;
            t.attr("tabindex", "-1"), t.focus()
        }))
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Although it is stated here that safari supports scroll with smooth
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior but even example doesn't work on safari

As a way out, I found a library with a polyfills, and in those browsers where it does not work it's replaced - https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll