# How can I smooth scroll on Safari when <a> clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this in my navbar:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="/#frase">¿Como funciona?</a>
</li>
```

I want to make the page scroll down slowly to the href. Now it's scrolling abruptly on Safari. For google chrome I have this and works fine:

```
<style>
  html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
</style>
```

I've tried implementing smooth scroll for safari using Javascript from another stack overflow questions but none of them worked.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a Safari equivalent for scroll-behavior: smooth;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011205/is-there-a-safari-equivalent-for-scroll-behavior-smooth)

Comment: Another dupe target option: [Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7717527/8068625)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari does not support `scroll-behavior: smooth;`

To implement smooth scrolling for internal anchor links, add the following slice of vanilla JavaScript (no jQuery required!):

```
(function() {
    scrollTo();
})();

function scrollTo() {
    const links = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll');
    links.forEach(each => (each.onclick = scrollAnchors));
}

function scrollAnchors(e, respond = null) {
    const distanceToTop = el => Math.floor(el.getBoundingClientRect().top);
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetID = (respond) ? respond.getAttribute('href') : this.getAttribute('href');
    const targetAnchor = document.querySelector(targetID);
    if (!targetAnchor) return;
    const originalTop = distanceToTop(targetAnchor);
    window.scrollBy({ top: originalTop, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
    const checkIfDone = setInterval(function() {
        const atBottom = window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset >= document.body.offsetHeight - 2;
        if (distanceToTop(targetAnchor) === 0 || atBottom) {
            targetAnchor.tabIndex = '-1';
            targetAnchor.focus();
            window.history.pushState('', '', targetID);
            clearInterval(checkIfDone);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

After including that code snippet, any anchor link with a class of `.scroll` will scroll to the target. No modifications are required, just drop it in.

Since you have used the class `.nav-link` for `<a>` tag you can replace scroll in the first line of the `scrollTo()` function to your anchor class name which is `.nav-link`.

[Official source of answer](https://perishablepress.com/vanilla-javascript-scroll-anchor/)

also do check whether you `href` is working fine?

Comment: that code no longer works it seems. how exactly does jquery animate scrolling, any idea?

Comment: @oldboy you can find alternative solution of this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229742/javascript-window-scroll-behavior-smooth-not-working-in-safari

Comment: that solution does not have the best functionality, but its def a solution nonetheless. i wonder how jquery achieves it

Comment: @oldboy for jquery you can see this: https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/browser-compatible-smooth-scrolling-with-css-js-jquery/

Comment: i believe jquery must use JS `animate` because that is the only way ive come across that creates a truly smooth scroll that can be throttled at diff rates

Answer (score 0):

You could use this script to enable smooth scrolling with backwards compatibility.

https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll

Also, change your href to `href="#frase"` the / is not needed.

Comment: This may not be a great option as it's since been deprecated.