# Horizontal Smooth Momentum Scrolling

Tags: javascript, horizontal-scrolling, smooth-scrolling

**THE PROBLEM:** I need to apply some mouse wheel smooth **horizontal** scrolling to this layout: https://jsfiddle.net/38qLnzkh/.

**ALTERNATIVE:** I've found this Script that does exactly what I want but it seems to work only vertically: [Butter.js](https://www.cssscript.com/smooth-momentum-scrolling-butter/). If you can make it work Horizontally it would probably solve all my problems.

**IMPORTANT:**

**1.** The Script should be disabled based on screen width and in touch devices.

**2.** It should accommodate a menu on top of everything like you seen in the fiddle.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**
In case it's not clear what I need, here are two examples with the effect I'm looking for:

https://nemesiscorporation.com/

https://www.tentwenty.me/about-us

---

**MY LAYOUT:**

HTML:

```
<main class="outer-wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <article class="section" id="a"><h2>01</h2></article>
        <article class="section" id="b"><h2>02</h2></article>
        <article class="section" id="c"><h2>03</h2></article>
        <article class="section" id="d"><h2>04</h2></article>
        <article class="section" id="e"><h2>05</h2></article>
        <article class="section" id="f"><h2>06</h2></article>
    </div>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
.outer-wrapper {
  width: auto;
  height: 100vw;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: auto;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left;
    margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.section {
    color: #000;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the mentioned lib: https://min30327.github.io/luxy.js/ You can set `data-horizontal="1"` for horizontal scrolling

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Josef. I think I've followed all the instructions but nothing seems to be happening... What am I doing wrong. Please have a look: [Fiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/s3zaLg72/1/)

Comment: I'm sorry, I just saw that this animates horizontal movement while you scroll vertically (like the letters on the [demo page](https://min30327.github.io/luxy.js/)). I'll find you something else. Sorry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've published an API on github that can easily solve this problem, below you'll find the code to do what you want.

Compared to yours I've just added the js code and the `<script>` in the HTML.

If you want to know more about it, [here you can find the documentation](https://github.com/CristianDavideConte/universalSmoothScroll).

**EDIT**
Since the requirements have changed a little bit and the API has been updated I've modified the example below so that it better fits the question.

Main changes to the answer:

- Now the js is inside a `init()` method called `onload`
- The css styles have been modified (`transform:rotate` brakes most of scrolling APIs)
- The support for the navbar's smooth scroll has been added
- The scrolling amount now depends on how much the user physically scrolls the mousewheel

```js
/* UPDATED 2022 ANSWER */
function init() {
    /*
     * Variables preparation
     */
    let yourWrapperElement = document.getElementsByClassName("outer-wrapper")[0];
    let whateverEaseFunctionYouWant = remaningScrollDistance => { return remaningScrollDistance / 15 + 1 };

    //Added support for navbar menu's smooth scrolling
    uss.hrefSetup();

    /*
     * As you asked for, we only apply the custom scrolling for desktop devices
     * by using the "wheel" event instead of the "scroll" or "touchmove" events.
     */
    yourWrapperElement.addEventListener("wheel", event => {
      /*
       * We want to overwrite the default scrolling behaviour
       * of your outer-wrapper component.
       */
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      uss.scrollXBy(event.deltaY, yourWrapperElement, null, false);             
    }, {passive:false});

    /*
     * We apply a the custom ease function
     * which will be used whenever our component is scrolled by the API
     */
    uss.setXStepLengthCalculator(whateverEaseFunctionYouWant, yourWrapperElement);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.outer-wrapper {
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh; /*  Changed to vh */
  width: 100vw; /* Added */
  /*transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh); ROTATING containers brakes 90% of scrolling APIs
  transform-origin: top left;*/
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  /*scroll-behavior: smooth; ISN'T NEEDED FOR MY API */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /*width: auto; NOT NEEDED IF WE USE FLEX-SHRINK 0
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh); ROTATING containers brakes 90% of scrolling APIs
  transform-origin: top left;*/
  margin: 0; /* not really needed */
  padding: 0; /* not really needed */
}

.section {
  color: #000;
  flex-shrink: 0; /* ADDED insted of the width/height of the wrapper */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#a { background-color: #ccc; }
#b { background-color: #fff; }
#c { background-color: #ccc; }
#d { background-color: #fff; }
#e { background-color: #ccc; }
#f { background-color: #fff; }


h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 200px;
  margin: 0;
}



/* MENU  _________________________ */



.logo {
  float: left;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
}

/* HEADER */

header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
}


/* HEADER LARGE */

header.large {
  height: 50px;
}

header.large .logo {
  width: 225px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  background: url('../images/logo-fireqa-green-500px.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;

  transition: 0.7s all;
  -moz-transition: 0.7s all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.7s all;
  -o-transition: 0.7s all;
}


/* UNORDERED LIST */

header.large ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
header.small ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
}

header.large li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  list-style-position: inside;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}


header.large li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #0E6245;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', 'arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-size: 25px;

  background-image: linear-gradient(#0E6245, #0E6245);
  background-position: 50% 80%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0% 4px;

  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

header.large li a:hover, a:focus {
  background-size: 60% 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/universalsmoothscroll@latest/universalsmoothscroll-min.js"></script>

<body onload = init()>


<main class="outer-wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <article class="section" id="a"><h2>01</h2></article>
        <article class="section" id="b"><h2>02</h2></article>
        <article class="section" id="c"><h2>03</h2></article>
        <article class="section" id="d"><h2>04</h2></article>
        <article class="section" id="e"><h2>05</h2></article>
        <article class="section" id="f"><h2>06</h2></article>
    </div>
</main>


<!-- MENU _____________________ -->


<header class="large">
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <a><div class="logo"></div></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#a">01</a></li>
            <li><a href="#b">02</a></li>
            <li><a href="#c">03</a></li>
            <li><a href="#d">04</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, Christian, for taking the time to present this solution. It works and It's of very easy implementation. This is very close to what I need. The fact that it's based on scrollDistance however doesn't allow users to pause the page exactly where they want. But it's a great solution nonetheless, If I can't find a better one I'll definitely use it. Much apreciated!

Comment: Hi David, based on the examples you provided i thought that you didn't need pixel-precision scrolling but if that's the case, the API i've provided here has 2 methods you could find helpful and they are: `uss.scrollYTo()` and  `uss.scrollIntoView()`.
The first one allows you to smoothly go to the exact y-axys coordinate of your scrollingElement (in this case the outer-wrapper) whereas the second one scrolls your container till the element you specified is visible (with an allignment that you may require) .
I hope you may find this helpful in case you can't find anything better !

Comment: Hi Christian, I do not need pixel precision, but it bothers me that the user can't position a section of the layout in the viewport where he wants it, which might leave part of that section out. That's my only issue, it's not the end of the World... I was just hoping for something more fluid like the examples I provided where the speed and amount of scrolling correlates with the usage of the mousewheel.  Don't get me wrong though, I'm really happy to have your solution and will be very grateful to use it if nothing closer to what I need comes along. Much appreciated!!!

Comment: Hi Cristian, I was very happily implanting my project using your script when today I realized it doesn't work in Firefox. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi David, all the API functions work correctly on firefox as far as i've tested, even the provided example.
So the problem may be due to the fact that in the example i've used the `event.deltaY` to understand by how much the user has scrolled: this works fine but the problem is that chrome and firefox provide two different values for the same ammount of scroll. Chrome uses the scroll value x 100 (that's why i put `event.deltaY / 100` ) meanwhile firefox uses the raw value (so the `/ 100` part messes things up). I've updated the code so that correctly works in firefox now !

Comment: Sorry, you're right, the API functions did work on Firefox, it was the difference in rendering that was making it unusable. Thank you for your explanation. It performs a lot better in Firefox now, although it scrolls about 3 times the distance it scrolls in other browsers. A lot better still. I've noticed other scrolling scripts have poor performance in Firefox. If this can't be improved, could we just cancel the script in Firefox?

Comment: Hi David, i would suggest to create 2 different variables: `minScrollDistance` (the one in the example i've provided) and `minScrollDistanceRaw` which will be the `minScrollDistance / A_NUMBER_OF_YOUR_CHOICE` and then applying `minScrollDistanceRaw` instead of `minScrollDistance` in the else statement of the wheel eventListener. If you've already noticed that the scrolling in firefox is 3 times the scrolling you have in chrome then you already know that `A_NUMBER_OF_YOUR_CHOICE` is `3`. I've updated the js code so that it's as clear as possible

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice package called [smooth-scrollbar](https://idiotwu.github.io/smooth-scrollbar/).

I've adjusted your example. It disables smooth scrolling for mobile devices, but otherwise it's just calling the package. And I've cleaned up some CSS.

```js
/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52855084/5312432 */
function isTouchDevice() {
  return window.matchMedia("(pointer: coarse)").matches;
}

function initSmoothScrolling() {
  const options = {
    damping: 0.1,
    alwaysShowTracks: true
  };
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".smooth-scrollbar");
  for (const element of elements) {
    Scrollbar.init(element, options);
  }
}

if (!isTouchDevice()) {
  initSmoothScrolling();
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.smooth-scrollbar {
  overflow: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.section:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.section:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #fff;
}

h2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 200px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<main class="smooth-scrollbar">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <article class="section"><h2>01</h2></article>
    <article class="section"><h2>02</h2></article>
    <article class="section"><h2>03</h2></article>
    <article class="section"><h2>04</h2></article>
    <article class="section"><h2>05</h2></article>
    <article class="section"><h2>06</h2></article>
  </div>
</main>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/smooth-scrollbar/8.5.3/smooth-scrollbar.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Josef, I appreciate your help but I've tested your example in all major browsers and it doesn't scroll. :(

Comment: I've updated the original question with some examples of what I'm looking for...

Comment: Ok, smooth, smooth when you click on scrollbar trail, but I do not understand this answer... the post author asked applying mouse wheel smooth horizontal scrolling: Your snippet 1) shows something which scrolls also vertically, 2) and does not work with mouse wheel vertically...