# Safari smooth sticky element

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I'm doing a website and trying to make a sticky element on this part :
[image]

Everything is ok on chrome / firefox but the sticky element is flickering on safari MacOS.
I tried to play with overflow /height etc.. but nothing seems to work.

A video of the issue : https://youtu.be/zNjn3uFHq3A

HTML code :

```css
  &--clicapp {
      // z-index: -1;
      min-height: 100vh;
      position: sticky;
      // top: 0;
      .Section__content {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 1.6rem;
        padding: 2rem;
        box-shadow: $shad;
        @include lg {
          flex-direction: row;
          background-color: $bk__light;
          border-radius: 0;
          padding: 0;
          box-shadow: none;
        }
        .Col {
          &--right {
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            margin-bottom: 4rem;
            @include lg {
              width: 55%;
              margin-bottom: 0;
            }
            //&::before {
            //  content: none;
            //  position: absolute;
            //  left: -12%;
            //  top: 47%;
            //  @include lg {
            //    content: url('~assets/img/path.svg');
            //  }
            //}
            ul {
              //height: 35rem;
              min-height: 130vh;
              margin: 0 auto;
              position: relative;
              overflow: auto;
              scroll-behavior: smooth;
              @include md {
                width: 44rem;
              }
              @include lg {
                margin-top: 8rem;
              }

              &::before {
                content: ' ';
                background-image: url('~assets/img/index/section-clicapp/degrade-up-mobile.svg');
                display: block;
                background-repeat: repeat;
                width: 100%;
                position: sticky;
                height: 50px;
                z-index: 1;
                top: -1px;
                pointer-events: none;
                @include lg {
                  background-image: url('~assets/img/index/section-clicapp/degrade-up.svg');
                }
              }
              &::after {
                content: ' ';
                background-image: url('~assets/img/index/section-clicapp/degrade-down-mobile.svg');
                display: block;
                background-repeat: repeat;
                width: 100%;
                position: sticky;
                height: 50px;
                z-index: 1;
                bottom: -1px;
                pointer-events: none;
                @include lg {
                  background-image: url('~assets/img/index/section-clicapp/degrade-down.svg');
                }
              }
              li {
                opacity: .2;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
                transition: all 0.5s;

                &.active {
                  opacity: 1;
                }

                h3 {
                  margin-top: 2rem;
                  margin-bottom: 2rem;
                }
              }
              li + li {
                margin-top: 5rem;
              }
            }
          }
          &--left {
            min-height: 1200px;
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;

            @include lg {
              width: 40%;
              margin: initial;
            }
            @include rwd(1281) {
              width: 45%;
            }

            .sticky {
              display: block;
              position: sticky;
              top: 0;
              margin-left: auto;
              margin-right: 90px;

              img {

              }
            }


          }
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<section
      id="scrollClicApp"
      class="Section Section--clicapp arrow"
      data-aos="fade-left"
      data-aos-duration="800"
      data-aos-offset="300"
    >
      <div class="container">
        <div class="Section__content Section__content--col">
          <div class="Col Col--left">
            <div class="sticky">
              <img
                alt="ClicScan"
                src="~assets/img/index/section-clicapp/clicapp-slide1.png"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Col Col--right">
            <h2>
              <span>ClicApp</span>
              <br/>
              L'application de gestion de votre clicScan
            </h2>
            <ul id="scrollList">
              <li class="active">
                <img
                  src="~assets/img/index/section-clicapp/analysis.svg"
                  alt="Analyse"
                />
                <h3>
                  Mesure de l'empreinte santé
                  <!-- <span>+ visuel de l’empreinte santé dans une tablette</span> -->
                </h3>
                <p>
                  Usense capte les données spectrales associées à chaque mesure.
                  C'est sur la base de cette empreinte santé unique que Usense
                  peut proposer des pistes de diagnostic précises.
                </p>
              </li>
              <li>
                <img
                  src="~assets/img/index/section-clicapp/ia.svg"
                  alt="Intelligence artificielle"
                />
                <h3>
                  Résultat d’analyse
                  <!-- <span>(visuel des valeurs brutes de biomarqueurs)</span> -->
                </h3>
                <p>
                  Une fois la mesure effectuée, les algorithmes Usense calculent
                  les concentrations de chaque biomarqueur. Usense propose une
                  lecture comparée aux valeurs de référence.
                </p>
              </li>
              <li>
                <img
                  src="~assets/img/index/section-clicapp/clear-visuel.svg"
                  alt="Créatinine"
                />
                <h3>
                  Calcul de ratio à la créatinine
                  <!-- <span>(page des ratios)</span> -->
                </h3>
                <p>
                  Visualisation immédiate des ratios à la créatinine afin
                  d'éliminer les variables écran qui gênerait le diagnostic. La
                  comparaison aux valeurs usuelles permet de se concentrer
                  rapidement sur les valeurs hors norme.
                </p>
              </li>
              <li>
                <img
                  src="~assets/img/index/section-clicapp/clear-visuel.svg"
                  alt="Créatinine"
                />
                <h3>
                  Aide au diagnostic
                  <!-- <span>(visuel data vizz Dashbaord)</span> -->
                </h3>
                <p>
                  Pour aiguiller toujours mieux le diagnostic, Usense propose
                  aussi de calculer différents indices de risque de pathologie.
                </p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Anyone having the same issue ?

Comment: An edit with some code is nice but a [repro] is far better because we can use the devtools to inspect. Here, the issue seems quite easy to fix tho, so that should be okay with a repro!

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56011281/8816585), it looks like `scroll-behavior: smooth` is not supported in Safari.

Hence, using this should solve the issue

```js
import smoothscroll from 'smoothscroll-polyfill'
smoothscroll.polyfill()
```

It's [pretty small](https://bundlephobia.com/package/smoothscroll-polyfill@0.4.4) so there should not be any issue in terms of performance.