# Why is scroll-behavior not working on my phone?

Tags: html, css, anchor

I added the **scroll-behavior** property in my CSS but it only works on the google chrome tool that allows me to see my website like if it was on a phone. When I load my website on my actual phone, there is no sliding effect. Any idea?

Here is what the code looks like :

```js
function scrollToSection(event) {
    if (supportsSmoothScrolling()) {
      return;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    const scrollToElem = document.getElementById("section");
    SmoothVerticalScrolling(scrollToElem, 300, "top");
  }
  
  function supportsSmoothScrolling() {
    const body = document.body;
    const scrollSave = body.style.scrollBehavior;
    body.style.scrollBehavior = 'smooth';
    const hasSmooth = getComputedStyle(body).scrollBehavior === 'smooth';
    body.style.scrollBehavior = scrollSave;
    return hasSmooth;
  };
   
  function SmoothVerticalScrolling(element, time, position) {
    var eTop = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var eAmt = eTop / 100;
    var curTime = 0;
    while (curTime <= time) {
      window.setTimeout(SVS_B, curTime, eAmt, position);
      curTime += time / 100;
    }
  }
  
  function SVS_B(eAmt, position) {
    if (position == "center" || position == "")
    window.scrollBy(0, eAmt / 2);
    if (position == "top")
    window.scrollBy(0, eAmt);
  }
```

```css
html, body {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid h-100 nopadding">
    <div class="row h-100 nopadding">
        <div class="col-lg-8 black nopadding text-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
            <a onclick="scrollToSection(event)" href="#more" class="more">Here is the button</a>
        </div>

        <div id="more"
            class="col-lg-4 white nopadding text-center d-flex flex-column align-self-center justify-content-center">
            Here is the section
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I didn't add all the page elements but the arrow represent the anchor tag in the code : [image]

Comment: What phone/browser are you using? Scroll-behavior is not supported by all browsers: https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-behavior. Also, you can remove the #more in the href.

Comment: I have an IPhone and I tried safari and Google chrome

Comment: Safari does not support the scroll-behavior property by default according to https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-behavior, it can be enabled via the "CSSOM View Smooth Scrolling" experimental features flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have noticed, Safari does not support the scroll-behavior CSS property (see [this](https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-behavior)). You'd need some JavaScript to achieve the same effect across different browsers. You may find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229742/javascript-window-scroll-behavior-smooth-not-working-in-safari).

**Update:**
This is a working code snippet of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64745703/2224657) (which combines the answers of [George Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52522150/2224657) and [terrymorse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64210741/2224657)).

```js
function scrollToSection(event) {
  if (supportsSmoothScrolling()) {
    return;
  }
  event.preventDefault();
  const scrollToElem = document.getElementById("section");
  SmoothVerticalScrolling(scrollToElem, 300, "top");
}

function supportsSmoothScrolling() {
  const body = document.body;
  const scrollSave = body.style.scrollBehavior;
  body.style.scrollBehavior = 'smooth';
  const hasSmooth = getComputedStyle(body).scrollBehavior === 'smooth';
  body.style.scrollBehavior = scrollSave;
  return hasSmooth;
};
 
function SmoothVerticalScrolling(element, time, position) {
  var eTop = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  var eAmt = eTop / 100;
  var curTime = 0;
  while (curTime <= time) {
    window.setTimeout(SVS_B, curTime, eAmt, position);
    curTime += time / 100;
  }
}

function SVS_B(eAmt, position) {
  if (position == "center" || position == "")
  window.scrollBy(0, eAmt / 2);
  if (position == "top")
  window.scrollBy(0, eAmt);
}
```

```css
body {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  height: 1000px;
}
section {
  margin-top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="scrollToSection(event)" href="#section">
    Redirect On section
</a>
  
<section id="section">
  Section Content
</section>
```

Comment: @Bonsaï, which one of the methods described do you not understand? There is a native JS solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64745703/2224657), but also Polyfill (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55932856/2224657) or jQuery (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57625722/2224657)

Comment: @Bonsaï I updated my answer with a working example, based on stackoverflow.com/a/64745703/2224657

Comment: Wow thanks for your answer! Is there a bug in the code because your code snippet doesn't work :/

Comment: I saw you made an edit, but now I can't click the button anymore. The problem is that if I use your code without the scroll-behavior, it don't work anymore :/ I see you get the element byID "section" in your js file, but I don't use section, may you look at my edit ?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I accidentally updated the snippet. It is working for me in Safari. Could you provide a snippet with the code that you tried? Alternatively you could also have a look at the polyfill smoothscroll, which will take care of scrolling: https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll

Comment: I tried to use polyfill but I didn't understand. I made and edit with a code snippet.